# Shopify pickadate query - change date conditions based on selection in dropdown on cart page

Tags: api, shopify

So I have a datepicker on my site, the conditions have been set but the dates available remain the same for all options in the delivery/collection dropdown on the cart page - I would like the dates available to change depending on selection in the dropdown.

http://mettricksbutchers.com/cart

What I would like to happen is this - for the dates available to change whether the customer selects collect from shop (3 shops available)  or delivery.

I have tried a number of solutions to similar problems I found online, but none have solved my issue without have two datepickers on the page.

Does anyone know how I can approach this or point me in the right direction please?

There is a clickcollect template in my shopify theme editor page which programmes the datepicker - already linked to the jsquery and I am using google api key to push the selected date to the cart page.

Thank you for your time